# Definition and implementation for function accepting an array or variable/rest parameters

Tags: typescript

A function `fn` has the overloaded signatures:

```
public fn(...arg:T[]);
public fn(args:T[]);
```

so that `fn` can be called using either `fn([T1,T2,T3])` or `fn(T1,T2,T3)`

What is the "best" definition for that function ? (one that encourages my IDE to enforce the typing and that avoids arguments type testing boilerplate as much as possible)

Obviously, I can implement a `fn(args)` definition and test `typeof arguments[0]` in the implementation, but it would seem that since both have a parameter of type `T[]`, something less generic can be done.

(typescript 1.0.1)

**EDIT**

What I would like to avoid is something like this:

```
public fn(...arg:string[]);
public fn(args:string[]);
public fn() {
    if (typeof arguments[0] === 'string') {
          //fn(...args:string[]) called
    }
    else {

    }
}
```

This seriously weakens the purpose of declaring

```
public fn(...arg:string[]);
public fn(args:string[]);
```

in the first place and this does not benefit from the fact that the parameter type is`string[]` in both cases

(declaring the definition with the implementation `fn()` as private would have been an improvement but all definitions must have the same visibility)

Comment: `avoids arguments type testing boilerplate as much as possible` e.g.?

Comment: @basarat - see edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to implement the rest parameter version. If you *really* need to call that version with an array, you still can, using `apply`:

```
class Example {
    test(...strArray: string[]) {
        alert(strArray.length.toString());
    }
}

var example = new Example();

example.test('a', 'b', 'c');

example.test.apply(null, ['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

Now, you won't get type checking on the arguments passed to apply - so if that is important then I recommend having two methods:

```
class Example {
    test(...strArray: string[]) {
        this.testWithArray(strArray);
    }

    testWithArray(strArray: string[]) {
        alert(strArray.length.toString());
    }
}

var example = new Example();

example.test('a', 'b', 'c');

example.testWithArray(['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

If you change an argument type in the final call here, you'll get type checking.

You can't overload a method with both because of the problem you describe in your question - so you can either use the TypeScript compiler to do the work (it will map the arguments for you) or do it all yourself if you want a single method for both. There is no magical way of getting both in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I will go with a mixture of both: two methods when I need to publicly expose both possibilities, a single method with the rest parameter version and internal `apply` calls, when I do not.